# Convert date to sql date

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I have a little problem with netbeans and SQL Developer. Failed to move to sql date Date. Netbeans freezes :S
the above error was the casting of date to sql.date.

Any solution? brings me crazy.

I attached pieces of my code and see if you can help me.
(i use jDateChooser)

```js
Main: 

java.util.Date d = FechaEntrada.getDate();
java.sql.Date fecha = new java.sql.Date(d.getDate());


        Entrada ent= new Entrada(Integer.parseInt(idEntrada.getText()),
                Integer.parseInt(idTaquilla.getText()),
                Integer.parseInt(Cantidad.getText()),
                fecha,
                Integer.parseInt(pPrecio.getText()));
    
        CrudEntrada.create(ent);
```

```js
Crud:


 public static boolean create (Entrada entrads) {
        
        String sql = "INSERT INTO ENTRADA VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 int nFilas = 0;
        
        try {
   PreparedStatement pstm = ConnectDB.conectar().prepareStatement(sql);
  
                   
   pstm.setInt(1, entrads.getId_entrada());
   pstm.setInt(2, entrads.getId_taquilla());
   pstm.setInt(3, entrads.getCantidad());
   pstm.setDate(4, entrads.getFecha());
            pstm.setDouble(5, entrads.getPrecio());
                        
                        
                        
   nFilas = pstm.executeUpdate();
   .
    .
   .
   .
            return (nFilas > 0) ? true : false;    
    }
```

Comment: Be aware that java.sql.date does not have a time component. You may want to look at java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> java.sql.Date fecha = new java.sql.Date(d.getDate());

try

> java.sql.Date fecha = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime())

Comment: No, I 've tried and does not work as usual :S

Comment: Get you give stack trace because looking at the code, it should not have any problem doing casting